# ¿Porqué no me aparece el Entry usando tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo un código en tkinter, agregué un Entry , pero al ejecutar no aparece, solo la ventana con el título.

Evidencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es este:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

ventana=Tk()
ventana.title("portafilex")
ventana.geometry("800x700")
#partes del programa
ingresar = Entry(ventana,width=30)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Te falta ubicar el entry en algún lugar en la ventana. Lo que estás haciendo es pintar una pintura sin colgarla en la pared. Tkinter no sabe magicamente donde esperas que el entry esté. Te recomiendo leer esta pagina para entender como posicionar elementos de tkinter: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/posicionar-elementos-en-tkinter/

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregarlo a tu ventana para que se visualice, en tu código lo único que estás haciendo es creando el entry pero solo está creado mas no colocado en la ventana, para hacer esto hay diversas maneras, una sería cololarlo con el método pack: `ingresar.pack()`

y la otra manera sería utilizando el metódo grid con el cúal puedes indicar la posición dónde deseas que se añada a la ventana: `ingresar.grid(row=1,column=1)`

Answer (score 0):

podrias probar con:

```
ingresar = Entry(ventana).place( y = 232,x = 13, width = 300)
```

el "y =" sirve para la cordenada "y"  "x =" sirve para la cordenada "x"